# Bibtex - how to change bibliography style to author last name, initials, year, article

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am wanting to display my references via natbib in the style: Author last name, Author first name initials, Year, Article etc etc. Before you say switch to biblatex - I have tried but am having issues with my .cls file which I cannot change at this stage. Also if I could number the bibliography without affecting my intext references that would be fantastic. Currently my references are showing as follows:

> Pablo  Benítez,  Rafael  García,  and  Juan  C.  Miñano.
>   Contactless  efficient  two-stage  solar  con-centrator for tubular
>   absorber.Applied  Optics,  36(28):7119,  October 1997.  ISSN
>   0003-6935,1539-4522.  doi:  10.1364/AO.36.007119. 
>   URLhttps://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-36-28-7119.77

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[round, authoryear, comma, longnamesfirst]{natbib}  

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
This is just a test \citep{benitez_contactless_1997}. 

\label{References}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style 
\bibliography{References} 

\end{document}
```

References.bib file

```
@article{benitez_contactless_1997,
    title = {Contactless efficient two-stage solar concentrator for tubular absorber},
    volume = {36},
    issn = {0003-6935, 1539-4522},
    url = {https://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-36-28-7119},
    doi = {10.1364/AO.36.007119},
    language = {en},
    number = {28},
    urldate = {2016-06-08},
    journal = {Applied Optics},
    author = {Benítez, Pablo and García, Rafael and Miñano, Juan C.},
    month = oct,
    year = {1997},
    pages = {7119},
    file = {ao-36-28-7119.pdf:/Users/EJSTurner/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/hjhi2l4a.default/zotero/storage/AAMGUHCN/ao-36-28-7119.pdf:application/pdf}
```

.cls file:

```
%%
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 2.75cm}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 2cm}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}
\supervisor  {}
\examiner    {}
\degree      {}
\authors     {}
\university  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {The University of Sydney}}
                {University Name}}
\UNIVERSITY  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {THE UNIVERSITY OF SYDNEY}}
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\department  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {School of Aerospace, Mechanical and Mechatronic Engineering}}
                {Department or School Name}}
\DEPARTMENT  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {SCHOOL OF AEROSPACE, MECHANICAL and MECHATRONIC ENGINEERING}}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\group       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Research Group Name}}
                {Research Group Name}}
\GROUP       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\faculty     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {}}
                {Faculty Name}}
\FACULTY     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {)}}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\addresses   {}
\subject     {}
\keywords    {}
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\Large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{University_of_Sydney}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the degree\par}
      {\LARGE Bachelor of Mechanical Engineering Honours \& Commerce \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large in the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par}
      {\large \textit{Supervisor}: Assoc. Prof. Michael Kirkpatrick}
      \vfill
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par}
    \bigskip
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par}
    {\normalsize \deptname \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize Bachelor of Mechanical Engineering Honours & Commerce\par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \@title \par}
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by \authornames \par}
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{References}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `Thesis.cls'.
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused. You want to number your bibliography without actually using the numbers? You have a class that imposes bibliographical constraints that you don't want to adhere to? What is this `Thesis` class and must you use it? (I keep seeing people using a class called `Thesis`, which seems to cause endless problems, and yet cannot be found in any obvious place. More than 'switch to `biblatex`, I'm inclined to say: 'do not use this class!')  But note that slightly modifying the class so that you can use `biblatex` is probably super-easy -- if you ask and post the class or a link to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response jon. I've inserted my .cls file (I didnt make it). It is very long and dirty though so not sure if anyone will be able to decode it!

Comment: Actually, there's nothing in the `.cls` that will prevent you from using `biblatex`. The only things that will prevent it currently are the relevant lines in the example `.tex` file you posted. (Off-topic: is `lstpatch.sty` really still required?)

Comment: @jon If you want to know more: [Our famous thesis template](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Ha, well I'm certainly often confused by templates, and I don't even use them!